# Can I delete .ftpquota file on server or not

Tags: cpanel, ftp, upgrade

I'm just doing upgrades alongside some cleaning on my server [cpanel], can I delete this file? does it harm my system or just resets (automatically gets created again with 0 0)?

Answer (score 3):

.ftpquota is a file used by your FTP deamon on the server, if you want it deleted, you need to disable the FTP server running on your hosting.