# Should I copy the .ftpquota file when moving a site

Tags: migration

I want to move the content of my top level website to a domain that is an add-on in the cPanel. I will be placing new content in the top level domain. Should I leave the `.ftpquota` behind in the top level domain?

Answer (score 1):

You should not copy (or delete) the `.ftpquota` file when moving the site.

The `.ftpquota` file relates to the FTP account used to transfer files and resides in the root directory that the FTP account has access to. It keeps track of FTP "usage". In other words, the number of *bytes* (and number of files) that have been transferred. It is a simple text file of the form:

```
2128 41791807
```

Where 2128 is the number of files transferred and the larger figure is the number of bytes.

Unless you are logged into the main hosting/FTP account (eg. the default cPanel FTP account) then you probably don't have permission to delete (or even read) this file.

Copying this file to a different location will probably be *meaningless*, unless you are perhaps backing up an FTP account?

If the file is deleted then it resets the "usage" stats for that FTP account (important if the FTP account has a "quota" assigned). The file will be regenerated when the FTP account next transfers a file (starting from zero again).

If 2+ FTP accounts share the same root directory then they also share the same `.ftpquota` file and "usage" stats.

Related questions:

- [Can I delete .ftpquota file on server or not](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/99104/can-i-delete-ftpquota-file-on-server-or-not)